# Add servlet.jar in my classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I have imported a google web app project and added the servlet.jar file but  I don not know how to set the servlet.jar file in my classpath. How do I go about doing that. Am new to eclipse and this is a project am collaborating with somebody. I am using a macbook.

Answer (score 0):

If you had received an App Engine project, then an Eclipse Import should have done the trick and setup the paths correctly.

Since, it is not done, you will need to do the following for an App Engine project.

- In your Eclipse project that you have imported, visit Project Properties and then Java Build Path.
- In the Libraries Tab, check if an App Engine SDK library is present or not. If yes , expand it, you will see the servlet-api.jar file.
- If not, Add Library from there and choose the current App Engine Library that you have set up on our system.

Comment: I downloaded the google webkit plugin in eclipse. does that help @Romin

Comment: I am assuming you have downloaded the Google Eclipse plugin : https://developers.google.com/eclipse/ and set things up. If you are not using Google Web ToolKit (GWT), I suggest that when you are creating a new App Engine application, then deselect the GWT SDK option in the Wizard screen.